# How to Access DIV element inside Repeater using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, repeater

So I have an ASP.NET repeater control with a textbox and a div with validation text that's hidden. I'm trying to display this div based on if special characters are entered in the textbox. I've managed to apply the jquery regex across all textboxes, but I'm trying to figure out how to apply the validation error to the textbox row where the input is being entered by the User, as I want the error div to display the message on this particular row. I can get it to work on the first row but since the repeater creates it's own control ID's in the HTML, I was wondering how to go about this. Here's my code:

```
$(function(){

$('[id*=txtbox1]').keyup(function()
{
    var Input = $(this).val();
    re = /[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi;
    var SplChar = re.test(Input);
    if(SplChar)
    {
        var replchar = Input.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
        $(this).val(replchar);
                    $('#ErrorDiv').show(); 
    }
});});



<asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
            <asp:textbox ID="txtbox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Questions") %>' />
            <div id="ErrorDiv" style="display: none;">No special characters</div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Any Suggestions ? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Post the resulting HTML and don't use `id="ErrorDiv"` as the IDs in an HTML document should be unique.

Comment: Should I add an asp label then instead ? As the HTML ID or the textboxes at least would be such as txtbox1_0, txtbox1_1, txtbox1_2, txtbox1_3, txtbox1_4.

Comment: Post the resulting HTML of the repeater...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class to your textbox html like so

`<asp:textbox ID="txtbox1" class="question" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Questions") %>' />`

So you can **replace**

`$('[id*=txtbox1]').keyup(function() ...`

to this

`$(".question").keyup(function() ...`

---

And this `#ErrorDiv` will not work.. since ID must be unique and your repeater will create multiple div with the same ID. So change `id="ErrorDiv"` to `class="errorDiv"`.

**wrong**

`$('#ErrorDiv').show();`

**correct**

```
// $('#ErrorDiv').show();
$(this).next(".errorDiv").show();
```

Comment: Thanks Sudarpo Chong, I took your advice and added the class instead of relying on IDs. This seemed to work, appreciate the help!

Comment: You are welcome, @Rankone. Glad to help. This is the common problem we encounter when working with asp net web forms ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem which you are facing is because textbox-id's are unique. so only solution is to Select elements using `getElementsByName` or by their `class` name.

Comment: Appreciate the help Webruster, yes based on the response above, this is the approach I went ahead with.